# Excel: Counting Icon Set to create a total rating in an Excel Worksheet

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I had a worksheet with 5 columns - each column has a total of points for each member in the list.

I applied the ICON SET CONDITIONAL FORMAT - (the "3 star" icon set).

then, excel ranks each member with a 100% star, 50% star and 0% star.

Now I need to sum this "stars" combined for all 5 columns - and make a new column - called "Five Stars Rank" -

I don't need the "stars" - only the sum...

like this:

```
>                   Speed | Strengh | Precision | IQ | Stamina | Total    
  1- Michael Smith:  1star| halfstar| halfstar  |none| 1 star  | **3**
  2- Carl Smith:     1star| 1star   | halfstar  |1star| 1 star |**4,5**
```

Any idea?

tks a lot!!

Comment: is 50% really present as halfstar or as 50%?

Comment: hi @GowthamShiva! tks for your help! the conditional format present the result as a halfstar. But I think this is for cells with values under "33%" (I use the default condition - presented in "Conditional Format > Icon Set> More Rules" - A "fullstar" is for "67%" values - and "halfstar" for 33%. But I dont know "THE FORMULA" to reach this %... (I select each column and apply the format - then the range is the column - the top values get a "fullstar" - the medium "halfstar" and lower ("emptystar").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the pattern classifies the scores relatively to the [min-max] of the formatted range. The classes are divided into 3 thirds `<33%, <67% and >67%`.

```
G2: 
=SUMPRODUCT(MATCH((B2:F2-MIN(B:F))/(MAX(B:F)-MIN(B:F)),{0,0.33,0.67})-1)/2
```

[image]

Comment: hi @a-s-h - sorry for the delay - I need to convert the solution for my language - or, better - for my numeric system - to test the solution. Tks a lot!! Great works!!! Daniel

Comment: Hi Daniel. Yeah I notice you have a different locale. Glad to help :)